# iOS pushing view controller not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I've got a uitabbarcontroller set as the root view of the window. One of the tabs in the tabbar is set to a subclass of uitableviewcontroller. What I'm trying to do is show a details view when one of the rows is touched so I implemented

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if (!detailViewController) {        
detailViewController = [[ItemDetailViewController alloc] init]; 

}   
[detailViewController setEditingArray:   
[list objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];  
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

}
```

in my table controller, but when I select the row, my detailview doesn't pop in. I added nslog to see if the function fires - and it does, but my detailview still doesn't show. Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tableViewController` should be placed inside a `NavigationController`. 
I guess you created `tableView` inside a tab bar.

```
TableViewControllerSubclass* table = [[TableViewControllerSubclass alloc] init];

UINavigationController* tableNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:table];

mainController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
mainController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:tableNav,..., nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a navigation controller (`[self navigationController]` is returning `nil`). Instead of having the table view controller as the root of the tab, make the tab's root a navigation controller containing the table view controller. You will now be able to push the detail controller from the table view controller.